# RubyMotion/BubbleWrap blocking HTTP requests support

Tags: rubymotion

I was looking at BubbleWrap HTTP support which seems to make aync requests. Is there way to make blocking HTTP requests using BubbleWrap or something else in RubyMotion.?

This is needed for HTTP requests where I am expecting a response that needs to be reported to the user.

Comment: AFMotion/AFNetworking is probably your best bet, or look at the source code for BW and use their code without the queue stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can call [NSData::dataWithContentsOfURL](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/NSData.html#dataWithContentsOfURL%3A-class_method)

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something for POST as well. Dont think this will work for POST.